# Java .split() not working

Tags: java, object, bufferedreader, readline

I am trying to split a line from a text file. The text file is being imported from an inventory system and I don't know how to make it formatted with a tabular format. I can't tell you what is in the file but I will explain what I'm talking about. Confidentiality...

Line 1:

name     order     sorder  assemblyID    desc     date

123 123 123     1-2-3 123-456-789 12-3 1\2\3

Line 2:

123 123 123     1-2-3 123-456-789 12 3 1\2\3

If you can see... The description column has a space in it. Which means it will allocate that into separate part of my array. First array is of size 7 but the second array will be 8. Here is what I have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    ArrayList < CustordData > list = new ArrayList < CustordData > ();
    CustordData cd = new CustordData();
    int[] array = new int[10];
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/Y");

    try {
      String read = null;
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Custord.txt"));
      while ((read = in .readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
        cd.setCustName(splited[0]);
        cd.setPurchaseOrder(splited[1]);
        cd.setSalesOrder(splited[2]);
        cd.setAssemblyID(splited[4]);
        cd.setOrderDesc(splited[5]);
        cd.setKitDate(format.parse(splited[6]));
      }
      for (CustordData d: list) {
        System.out.println(d.getCustName() + d.getPurchaseOrder() + d.getSalesOrder() + d.getAssemblyID() + d.getOrderDesc() + d.getKitDate() + d.getShipDate() + d.getPricePer() + d.getTotal());
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: You will have to parse this manually. How do you _know_ that the column description has a space in it? And not some other column? Unescaped delimiters in a delimited file are ambiguous and the program cannot read your mind.

Comment: As Boris says, Based on that second example, either 5, 6, OR 7 could have the space. You need to escape the delimiter or come up with a way to figure out what has the space better.

Answer (score 2):

If you are **certain** that only one column will have extra spaces, and that it will be **always the same column**, you could still use split but you would do something like so:

```
Let N be the index of the description column, 
Assign columns [1, N-1] to the data you need
Assign columns [N, TotalColumns - 1] to description
Assign column TotalColumns to date
```

Something like so:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   String noSpaces = "123 123 123 1-2-3 123-456-789 12-3 1\\2\\3";
   String withSpaces = "123 123 123 1-2-3 123-456-789 12 3 1\\2\\3";

   String[] splitNoSpaces = noSpaces.split("\\s+");
   printData(splitNoSpaces);

   String[] splitWithSpaces = withSpaces.split("\\s+");
   printData(splitWithSpaces);

}

private static void printData(String[] data)
{
    int totalColumns = data.length;

    System.out.println("Name: " + data[0]);
    System.out.println("Order: " + data[1]);
    System.out.println("SOrder: " + data[2]);
    System.out.println("AssemblyID: " + data[3]);
    System.out.print("Description: ");
    for(int i = 4; i < totalColumns - 2; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("AssemblyID: " + data[totalColumns - 1]);
}
```

Yields:

```
Name: 123
Order: 123
SOrder: 123
AssemblyID: 1-2-3
Description: 123-456-789 
AssemblyID: 1\2\3
Name: 123
Order: 123
SOrder: 123
AssemblyID: 1-2-3
Description: 123-456-789 12 
AssemblyID: 1\2\3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that only problem is in description then test lenght of array. Then join array from index 5 to array lenght - 1.
KitDate will be last field of array.